# Multiple images are not uploaded using jquery ajax in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, mysqli

In my code I have an input field having name `product_image` where I want to upload and insert multiple files into my database like this `img1.jpg,img2.jpg,img3.jpg`. But Now, what happen when I select `4 files` i.e. `img1.jpg,img2.jpg,img3.jpg,img4.jpg` only `img4.jpg` store in my database and only this file are moving in my folder.

view:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            product_name = $("#product_name").val();
            var formData = new FormData();
            $.each($("#product_image"), function (i, obj) {
                $.each(obj.files, function (j, file) {                    
                    formData.append('product_image[' + i + ']', file);
                });
            });
            formData.append('product_name', product_name);
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                data:formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/products",
                success:function(data){
                    $("#success_upload").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="product_name" name="product_name">
<input type="file" id="product_image" name="product_image[]" multiple>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" name="submit">
```

Controller:

```
public function products()
{
    $dataInfo = array();
    $files = $_FILES;
    $cpt = count($_FILES['product_image']['name']);
    for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
    {           
        $_FILES['product_image']['name']= $files['product_image']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['product_image']['type']= $files['product_image']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name']= $files['product_image']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['product_image']['error']= $files['product_image']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['product_image']['size']= $files['product_image']['size'][$i];
        $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
                $this->upload->do_upload('product_image');
                $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
                $name_array[] = $upload_data['file_name'];
                $fileName = $upload_data['file_name'];
                $images[] = $fileName;
    }
    $fileName = $images;
    $data = array(
            'product_name' => $this->input->post('product_name'),
            'product_image' => implode(",",$fileName),
        );
    $sql = $this->db->insert('add_product',$data);
    if($sql == true)
    {
        echo '<p style="color:green;">New Product Added</p>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<p style="color:red;">Unable to Proceed!</p>';
    }
}
private function set_upload_options()
{   
    $config = array();
    $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH.'resource/product/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['max_size']      = '1024';
    $config['overwrite']     = FALSE;
    return $config;
}
```

So, How can I upload and insert multiple files into my database? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: Check here my answer for multiple file upload [Multiple file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53941916/php-ajax-multiple-file-upload-with-new-array/53942728#53942728)

Comment: I have got the solution I have change some code in my jquery file : var fileInputs = $('#product_image');
    var formData = new FormData();
    $.each(fileInputs, function(i,fileInput){
     if( fileInput.files.length > 0 ){
      $.each(fileInput.files, function(k,file){
       formData.append('product_image[]', file);
      });
     }
    });

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert and move multiple images via jQuery AJAX in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54003617/insert-and-move-multiple-images-via-jquery-ajax-in-codeigniter)

Comment: Sir, because I am not getting exact output but now I have got solution. Thank you for your support @SherifSalah

Comment: @samorten .. when you don't get the desired output, you can always modify your original question until you get the answer that suits your case then accept that answer but not to ask multiple questions, i hope you understand that.